# Phone number to call Ionic 3

Tags: ionic3

I am building an Android app with Ionic 3 and I want to do the following. I have a text phone number which I display in my app and I want to make it clickable, and when the user clicks the phone will be opened with the loaded phone number. Please note that I do not want the app to call that number only to load the number in the phone. I think there is something similar in Android but I want to know for Ionic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use standard html for that: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/click-to-call/